# Unable to initialize UINavigationController in an iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My application has the following design:

```
[Information view (UIViewController)] > 
    [Login/Signup View (UINavigationController)]
```

After information view has delivered the essesntial information to user's screen, I am using following code to initialize Login/SignUp view as the root UINavigationController and display it on user's screen.

```
loginViewController *loginVC = [[loginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *loginNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
loginVC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
loginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self showViewController:loginVC sender:self];
```

But while running the application, Xcode says "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported" and points to the following code block:

```
UINavigationController *loginNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
```

Is it an incorrect way of initializing UINavigationController?

AppDelgate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ViewController *rootVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];//ViewController == Information View
    self.window.rootViewController=rootVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @matt I am new to iOS dev but I am thinking of designing the application in the following way: > UIViewController for the initial view that delivers the Terms and Conditions to the end user. > After that the Login/SignUp view as UINavgationController so that when a user taps "Login", the username/password screen can utilize a back button, from UINavigationToolbar, to Login/SignUp View. Similar approach for Sign Up view as well.